# What's the best tactics to avoid zombies in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

I crawl, crouch and whatnot to try and avoid zombies. Usually I'm alright but once a zombie detect me I always manage to pull them with me forever until I am so tired that they catch up and eat me. What should I do to avoid this annoying recurrent occurence?

I've heard that zombies are less frequent in the forest, but I'm not sure. Perhaps someone with more knowledge could enlighten me on that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dayzguides made [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XvbSGxtrXk) which gives excellent guidance. A quick summary:

- Avoid them by crawling if at all possible
- Run up hills in a zig-zag (ideally a hill with trees on) and crawl as soon as you are out of sight of them
- Go into a building that has at least two doors - immediately leave by the 2nd door and crawl away

Not much else to it - the only other option is to shoot/smash in their heads.